# Sum duplicated columns in dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, datatable, tidyverse

Hello i have the following dataframe :

```
colnames(tv_viewing time) <-c("channel_1", "channel_2", "channel_1", "channel_2")
```

Each row gives a the viewing time for an individual on channel 1 and channel 2, for instance for individual 1 i get :

```
tv_viewing_time[1,] <- c(1,2,4,5)
```

What I would like is actually a dataframe that sums up the values of duplicated columns.
I.e. I would get

```
colnames(tv_viewing time) <-c("channel_1", "channel_2")
```

Where for instance for individual 1 i would get :

```
tv_viewing_time[1,] <- c(5,7)
```

As all two row entries are summed when they correspond to duplicated column names.

I have looked for an answer but all suggested on other threads did not work for my dataframe case.
Note that there are many more duplicated columns, so i am looking for a solution that can be efficiently applied to all my duplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use `split.default` with `rowSums`

```
sapply(split.default(tv_viewing_time, 
       sub("\\.\\d+$", "", names(tv_viewing_time))), rowSums)
```

-output

```
# channel_1 channel_2 
#       5         7
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
tv_viewing_time %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>%
  group_by(name = str_remove(name, "\\.\\d+$")) %>% 
  summarise(value = sum(value)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value)
# A tibble: 1 x 2
#  channel_1 channel_2
#      <dbl>     <dbl>
#1         5         7
```

#### data

```
tv_viewing_time <- data.frame(channel_1 = 1, channel_2 = 2, 
        channel_1 = 4, channel_2 = 5)
```

Comment: Hey Akrun! Unfortunately this would not work, because i have duplicates over other type of variables (i.e. channel_1 and channel_2 have duplicates info on viewing time, but also on favorite program, on most watched daypart ... )

Comment: Ideally, whenever i would have to exact duplicate columns in my data frame (there are around 30) i would sum them.

Comment: @Lola1993 Just use `.~` instead of `the column name.  It will select all other columns grouped by 'channel'

Comment: !! Argh.. I just realised my syntax was wrong. I have colnames(tv_viewing_time) <- c("Channel_1", "Channel_2", "Channel_1", "Channel_2") and then numerical values in all of them..

Comment: @Lola1993 please update your input data and expecetd output

Comment: you are brilliant!! Thank you so unbelievably much!!